# Carousel not scaling the same way as the background image

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have the following markup:

```
<section class="block">

<img class="img-background" src="assets/background_banner.png" alt="" >

    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="active item">
          <img src="assets/banner_1.png" alt="" >
                     </div>
```

And the CSS like this:

```
.img-background{
position:absolute;
margin-left:50%;
left:-512px;
top:0px;
z-index:1;
}

.carousel{
    position:absolute;
margin-left:50%;
left:-512px;
top:0px;
z-index:2;
}

.carousel .item {
    width: 100%; /*slider width*/
    height: auto; /*slider height*/

}
.carousel .item img {
margin-left: 0%;
    width: 100%; /*img width*/

}
/*full width container*/
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .block {
 margin-left: -20px;
        margin-right: -20px;
    }
}
```

It works when the browser is full screen. I have a background image and a carousel slide on top of that. But when I make the browser smaller the carousel stays big while the image scales. I want them both to scale the same way. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to scale the image along with the carousel, then add width: 100%; and see what happens.

```
.img-background{
position:absolute;
margin-left:50%;
left:-512px;
top:0px;
z-index:1;
width: 100%;
}
```

Although an example of working code would be better to debug.

Personally I would use the image as a background image. Perhaps remove it from the HTML and add it to your CSS like so:

```
.block {
    background: url(assets/background_banner.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: somehow when I add the background tag to css, the image won't show. That would be the ideal way to do this. I got to play with the 100%, because it's now bigger than the carousel.

Comment: then your path to the image is not correct. I don't know what your path is, so I assumed you'd figure it out. Try 'background: url(./assets/background_banner.png) no-repeat;'

Comment: It's weird, I checked the path, but that was not the issue. I got it to work though. I had to add the 100% and place the image in the carousel. Thanks